# to_number function in sql

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

i could not understand why following code
SQL>

```
Select to_number('1234.64', '9999.9') from Dual;
```

returns  this number    1234.6?is it  something like rounding  ,truncation or?please help me to  understand this code,i know to_number  functions,i have used many times this code for simple chars,but here it is  not clear  anything

Comment: What brand of database are you using? the SQL implementations differ...

Comment: Test `to_number('1234.65', '9999.9')` and if your answer is `1234.7` it's rounding.

Comment: @dato, what result would you have expected this to return?

Comment: i dont know really  even this does not work in oracle,i have see this format  here http://ss64.com/ora/syntax-to_number.html

Comment: "All number format models cause the number to be rounded to the specified number of significant digits."
Number Format Models of Oracle Database SQL Language Reference 11.2: [link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements004.htm#i34570)

Answer (score 2):

This looks a lot like Oracle, but I suspect that the result would be similar in any SQL that used to_number.

The to_number function takes two arguments: the string to be converted to a number, and the format string for the conversion.

In the example, '12345.64' is the string to be converted, while '9999.9' is the format string. In this format string, a 9 stands for a digit while a . stands for the decimal point.

So the function is asking to convert the string '12345.64' to a number with up to 4 digits to the right of the decimal point, and only 1 digit after the decimal point.

The second argument is optional - under normal circumstances, I would omit it.

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
SELECT to_number('1234.64', '9999.99') from Dual;
```

Your mask tells engine you want just one decimal, so number gets rounded.
If you want to get exact number, don't specify any mask:

```
SELECT to_number('1234.64') from Dual;
```

Comment: @Ariel: I read _"why ... returns this number 1234.6?"_, so what should I think? Maybe I missed the point, I'm not telling you the contrary... but which was the point then? Thanks :)

Comment: @dato: I beg your pardon if my answer was not the one you were searching. If so, please tell me and I will delete it immediately!

Comment: @Marco As I understood the question he wanted to understand how/whether it rounds/truncates the number. Not how to get the original number. It could be that I'm the one who didn't understand the question :)

Comment: @Ariel: well, so let's say it's not clear ;) Anyway @Michael comment was correct: _"`to_number('1234.65', '9999.9')` and if your answer is `1234.7` it's rounding"_